# If interest rate policy were to disappear tomorrow, how would we/could we manage inflation?

Tags: inflation, interest-rate, monetary-policy, central-banking

Inflation has obviously become a big issue over the last couple of years again, and I've read people complaining that the inflation comes from increased prices of energy imports, (namely oil and gas), and that interest rate policy from central banks is (in this person's view) bad, because there may be little to no inflation (or even deflation!) in locally-made goods, but the interest rate doesn't discriminate (unsure how valid this is, but I digress).

It got me wondering: if interest rate policy as a tool were to disappear tomorrow, how could we/would we manage inflation? What ideas have been proposed as other ways of managing inflation, and how do they stack up? Are there any policies which (even if theoretical right now) would be better for managing inflation than the tools we have right now? Why haven't they been tried?

Comment: If interest rate policy disappeared as a tool, that would mean the Federal Reserve would effectively stop existing, right? No more interest on excess reserves, and no emergency loans because it would be impossible to set an interest rate for them. Then we would go back to the pre-central-banking model of interest rates.

Comment: Price controls, goods rationing, inadequate amounts of money and severe restrictions on borrowing/lending have each been tried - usually with predictable negative results (including inefficient ways of avoiding the resulting distortions)

Comment: @user253751 I guess they _could_ stop existing, but they don't necessarily _have_ to. I was thinking of if they, or another government body were fighting inflation using other means, not really a return to the days of wildcat banks (though I guess that is a valid answer )

Comment: @tvqt If they do deposits that pay interest they have to decide an interest rate, which is interest rate policy, but if they don't pay interest they can avoid that. If they do loans they always need an interest rate, which would be interest rate policy, so they couldn't do loans. What else do they do that's not interest rate policy? OMOs? But they do OMOs to influence the interest rate, so they probably wouldn't.

Comment: @user253751 the way the central bank sets interest rate policy is through " setting the interest rate on overnight loans in the money market (‘the cash rate’)." see (https://www.rba.gov.au/monetary-policy/) I'm simply saying if that was no longer an option for them, (i.e they no longer provided overnight loans), nor any other instruments for controlling interest rates

Comment: I was thinking someone would come up with some creative ideas, like a floating tax rate or something. Surely there has been some research on this...but I'd also be happy with wild speculation/theory

Comment: @user253751 did I say they did?

Comment: Does no interest rate policy mean there's a fixed supply of money? Then we should expect long-term deflation inverse to technological progress.

Comment: @user253751 it means that what the central bank does right now wouldn't exist/wouldn't be allowed. The point isn't the scenario, but more an exploration of different alternatives to buying treasuries/adjusting the fed funds rate